# all 1000 scanned ports on 10.18.80.115 are in ignored states как исправить?

Tags: сеть, tcp, kali-linux, port

Я играю CTF TryHackMe RootMe, делаю скан `nmap sC -sV 10.18.80.115`, и дает такой ответ:

```
all 1000 scanned ports on 10.18.80.115 are in ignored states
Not shown: 1000 closed tcp ports (reset)
```

Я попробовал сканировать все порты, но снова дает такой же ответ. Что делать?